# OpenGL shading not working. Object looks solid colored

Tags: opengl, glut, lighting

I am currently trying to get into OpenGL shading and lighting to display a 3D model exported from Blender in a simple GLUT window.

I tried to display the typical glutSolidTeapot to validate my OpenGL settings.
With the Teapot everything looks perfectly fine as can be seen in the pic below.

[image]

If I now want to replace the teapot with my own Blender-exported model, the shading doesn't work. The model ( a car rim ) just looks solid-colored.
The color changes when the model is rotated, but it stays solid all the time.

[image]

What does glutSolidTeapot do under the hood to draw the teapot model?

Here's the code I'm using to set up OpenGL :

```
void SetupRC()
{
    glClearColor(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1.0);

    // Enable lighting and the light we have set up
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    //Set lighting parameters
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_POSITION,light_position);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT,light_ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);

    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_DIFFUSE);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // Enable shading
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    // Set up the projection parameters
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 20.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glEnable(GL_AUTO_NORMAL);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
}
```

And the code to repaint the frames :

```
void RenderScene(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -2.5f);

    glRotatef(xRot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(yRot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // set input data to arrays
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, BlenderGuru_CarWheelVerts);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

    GLfloat ambConst[] = { 0.24725, 0.1995, 0.0745, 1.0};
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, ambConst);

    GLfloat diffConst[] = { 0.75164, 0.60648, 0.22648, 1.0 };
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, diffConst);

    GLfloat specConst[] = { 0.628281, 0.555802, 0.366065, 1.0 };
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, specConst);

    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, 51.2);

    // draw data
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, BlenderGuru_CarWheelNumVerts);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: Is your model totally flat on the visible side? If so, AUTO_NORMALS will generate same normals for all vertices, and - assuming directional lighting - you'll have same colour for all triangles.

Comment: Blender's option to export normals is disabled by default.... enabling it and using the normal pointer when drawing, everything's working fine. Thanks to all you guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are exporting from Blender, your exported data will most likely also contain normals. If not, make sure you generate them for your model and export them. You need normal data for your lighting to work.

The call to [`glEnable(GL_AUTO_NORMAL);`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnable.xml) does not do what you might think it does. It will only

> generate normal vectors when either `GL_MAP2_VERTEX_3` or `GL_MAP2_VERTEX_4` is used to generate vertices.

So export normal data yourself and use this, or perhaps calculate the normals from the mesh data that is available to you.

Comment: If you look at the OP's code you'll see, he doesn't supply normals at all.

Comment: @datenwolf It was indeed awkwardly and inappropriately phrased. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your code lacks loading/setting normal data. Without normals, lighting doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Blender didn't export them for some reason. I will look into it again